# Android Marshmallow DexPathList NoSuchMethodException makeDexElements

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
Android Marshmallow DexPathList  NoSuchMethodException makeDexElements with parameters [class java.util.ArrayList, class java.io.File, class java.util.ArrayList] not found in class dalvik.system.DexPathList
```

But `Android5.1` is OK, from Where I can download the Android `Marshmallow DexPathList` Source Code?

Comment: [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore-snapshot/+/ics-mr1/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexPathList.java) are you looking for something like this ?

Comment: @ShvetChakra it's ICS , not Marshmallow,but thx!

Answer (score 0):

It's because Google has changed the method name and signature on Marshmallow, here is the working solution:

```
Method makeDexElements = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ?
                findMethod(dexPathList, "makePathElements", List.class, File.class, List.class) :
                findMethod(dexPathList, "makeDexElements", ArrayList.class, File.class, ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: Can you link to or provide the source of `findMethod`?